# Before Filter on a rack ( sinatra ) based app in RoR applications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, sinatra

I have a sinatra application, mounted in my rails app.

```
match "/my_sinatra_app" => MyApp, :anchor => false
```

Is there a way to execute a Rails before filter on rails on all `/my_sinatra_app` urls. ?

Comment: You could define before filters inside the sinatra application. Any reason not to use that functionality?

Comment: Iam using this gem https://github.com/ejschmitt/delayed_job_web and want to have my own authentication, so want to redirect the user using a before_filter. This gem is in sinatra and my app is rails

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I ran into a similar problem with Sidekiq Web.

To get around this we can use [route constraints](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#advanced-constraints).

In your routes file constrain the route to the mounted application:

```
require "sidekiq/web"
mount Sidekiq::Web, at: "/sidekiq", constraints: AdminConstraint.new
```

Then in the `AdminConstraint`, you need to place the calls that are in your `before_filter` that are applicable for your application's authentication. So for example if I had the following in my `ApplicationController`:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate

  def authenticate
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:email])

    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
    end
  end
end
```

I would put the following in the constraint:

```
class AdminConstraint
  def matches?(request)
    return false unless request.session[:user_id]

    user = User.find(request.session[:user_id])

    # Only show if user is a super admin
    user.present? && user.super_admin?
  end
end
```